# Valuing Long-Term (5+ year) Cliquet Options

Tags: options, volatility, equities, exotics

I'm trying to figure out how to value long term equity cliquet options with expirations 5+ years out. Even for SPX cliquets, vol surfaces are from what I can tell non-existent. Where would someone get data for something like this? I have to imagine that it is in some way simulated. Can someone point me towards some research papers or documentation regarding valuations of long term path dependent options (or something similar)?

Comment: A good starting point would indeed be the question of how to price a simple vanilla option for such long expiries. Only when this point is OK (and you'll find out it's more of an art than a science), maybe then you can look into cliquets, knowing that these structures are amongst the more tricky to price correctly since they do not just depend on the IV at 5Y+ (which is already hard to define), but on it's future (conditional) dynamics along all the path.

Comment: @Quantuple I guess I should have been more specific. I am looking to value these using a stochastic volatility model w/ jump diffusion. The volatility for the calibration is the more important part of this. That is really what I am looking for. It doesn't seem obvious what kind of volatility inputs would be sufficient for these models to actually be useful.

Comment: Regardless of the model you are using, what will be crucial is the dynamics of the future IVs. Which you need to somewhat factor in. So what I'm saying is that it's not just LT IV today that matters, it's how the whole surface moves under the model: is the embedded dynamics realistic, can you compute breakeven levels? Jumps are not really useful for LT options, or do you mean double jumps in price/volatility. I think a good first read is Begomi's Smile Dynamics series of papers

Comment: @Quantuple That helps a lot. Thank you